# Appropriate way to add "media" files to c/c++ project in netbeans IDE

Tags: c++, file, netbeans, project

I have a a c/c++ project in netbeans 6.7 . The project requires a .dll file be located in the same directory as the .exe file, and it also needs a "media" directory (which contains a bunch of png files) within the same directory. I'd like to set it up so netbeans will automatically do this for me. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the Makefile, specifically the `.build-post` target, and put there some `cp` commands to copy the required files next to the .exe.